# How is "core" and "processor" defined on a Mac?

Tags: mac, cpu

Reading [this article](http://docs.hpc.shef.ac.uk/en/latest/parallel/index.html) I see the following phrase:

> Parallel Computing uses more than one core. A core (also called
>   processor) is capable of executing one thread of computation.

From that description I take away that *core* and *processor* are synonyms - they mean the same thing.

But when I look at the MacBook Hardware description I can see the following:

[image]

From that description the MacBook has 1 processor but 2 cores. This cannot be right.

Where is the mistake? Is the definition incorrect I have found? Or is the MacBook display showing incorrect content?

Comment: Modern usage is that "processor" typically denotes a physical package containing one or more processing cores.

Comment: If I understand you correct, you are saying that the definition is incorrect, and the Mac information is correct?

Comment: For a single core processor the definition is correct, a core is synonymous with a processor. They are called the same thing interchangeably. Once there are more cores in a package or more packages in a system you need to have a word that describes a collection of cores.

Comment: I still do not understand. Now, which definition is incorrect?